# Precautions to take when travelling alone around Ireland

Tags: safety, ireland, solo-travel, female-travellers

I am thinking of visiting Ireland during October (Dublin, Cork, Killarney and ring of Kerry). That will be my first time travelling alone. As a woman I am already in a disadvantaged position. So what precautions should I take?

Are there any areas or types of establishments or means of transportation that I should avoid?
Is it wise to say that am travelling alone if I asked?

Comment: Katia - as you're not a new user, you may be familiar with the [help] which does ask that you only ask one question per post.  Could you split them up into separate questions?  In addition, you've asked subjective questions - "should I prefer" is VERY subjective and likely to get it closed.

Comment: @MarkMayo I've removed a bit of cruft. I think the question can be answered reasonably objectively — are there any precautions that women traveling alone should take in Ireland?

Comment: so, I have to split my questions in more than one topics, or just make it more general, and avoid writing questions?
and I just have not to use words with opinion references,?

Comment: @Gilles - cheers, it was really the 'should I take a bus' that was subjective, and that combined with the multiple questions meant it should be put on hold at that point. I've voted to reopen now.  Katia - yeah, phrases like "should I" or "what do you think.." tend to be frowned upon, and multiple questions in one don't work well.

Answer (score 9):

As @user1291332 has stated Ireland is a safe place to travel just try to avoid the city buses at night if you are on your own. While there are few incidents on them a taxi would be a safer option though a bit more expensive.

Kerry isn't as well connected as the major cities (as you would expect) so it might do no harm doing a bit of research about where you want to go and when. At night your best bet again are taxis as there will be little to no public transport services available.

Also be careful at night to whom you are talking to, avoid suspiciously looking strangers.

Just treat your safety as you would if you were at home and you will be fine.

Here are some other useful links:

[National Rail Network (Iarnród Éireann)](http://www.irishrail.ie/)

[National Bus Network (Bus Éireann)](https://ecommerce.buseireann.ie/asp/eTicket_SelectTicket.asp?gclid=CIO6qr6AnrkCFYg72wodIwYAZQ)

Comment: "As for should you say if your traveling alone. I would judge your answer depending on who your talking to": what are you trying to say, it does not sound like something understandable, does it?

Comment: All I meant by this is that 99% of the time it will be OK to say your traveling alone just take care if your talking to someone you get a strange feeling off.

Answer (score 7):

Ireland, in general, is a fairly safe place to travel. You should have no problems on public transport. However do take care in bigger cities, such as Cork and Dublin at night.

Also see http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ireland#Stay_safe